# How to vectorize operations over several rows in a matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with Trimesh, and trying to compute some statistics on the meshes. One of the possible statistics (and the one I am using to illustrate the question) is a histogram of the areas of 3 random vertices of the mesh. Currently I am doing the following, but I would like to know if there's any way to avoid using a loop.

```py
def CalcArea(self, p):
    return 0.5 * np.linalg.norm(np.cross(p[1]-p[0], p[2]-p[0]))

v_c = self.mesh.vertices.copy()
np.random.shuffle(v_c)
areas = [self.CalcArea(v_c[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(v_c[:-2]))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html) [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) is your friend :-).

`np.cross` and `np.linalg.norm` work on arrays of vectors as well. And they support the powerful keyworded argument `axis`.

I'm assuming your `v_c` has the shape `(N, 3)`, where `N` is your number of vertices. Let's assume it's a multiple of three for simplicity, then:

```py
N = 30
v_c = np.random.random((N, 3))
v1 = v_c[N//3:2*N//3, :] - v_c[:N//3, :]
v2 = v_c[2*N//3:, :] - v_c[:N//3, :]
area = 0.5*np.linalg.norm(np.cross(v1, v2), axis=1)
```

Note that this involves the creation of temporary arrays so maybe keep an eye out for very large `N`.